# Can't use case & aggregation correctly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

**Cash_table**

```
ID          Cash   Rates  Amount
1           50     3      16
2           100    4      25
3           130    10     7
3           130    10     6
4           13     7      1.8
5           30     8      2.5
5           30     10     1
6           10     5      2
```

What I want as a result is to cumulate all the entries that have a **Count(id)>1** like this:

```
ID          New_Cash         New_Rates  New_Amount
1           50               3           16
2           100              4           25
3           130              10+10       130/(10+10)
4           13               7           1.8
5           30               8+10        30/(8+10)
6           10               5           2
```

So I only want to change the rows where Count(id)>1 and leave the rest like it was.

For the rows with count(id)>1 I want to sum up the rates and take the cash and divide it by the sum of the rates. The Rates alone aren't a problem since I can sum them up and group by id and get the desired result.

The problem is with the New_Amount column:

I am trying to do it with a case statement but it isn't working:

```
   select id, 
   cash as new_cash,
   sum(rates) as new_rates,
   (case count(id)
   when 1 then amount 
   else cash/sum(nvl(rates,null))
   end) as new_amount
   from Cash_table
   group by id
```

Comment: "it isn't working" isn't very helpful - do you get an error, or wrong results, or something else? What should happen if the `cash` values are different for an ID - what would you show/calculate `new_cash` as?

Comment: Sorry, the error is saying 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function" which I don't get since I am grouping by id. I think i am doing something wrong in the case statement. The cash values are always the same for the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the cash value is always the same for an ID, you can group by that as well:

```
select id, 
  cash as new_cash,
  sum(rates) as new_rates,
  case count(id)
    when 1 then max(amount)
    else cash/sum(rates)
  end as new_amount
from cash_table
group by id, cash
order by id

        ID   NEW_CASH  NEW_RATES NEW_AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         50          3         16
         2        100          4         25
         3        130         20        6.5
         4         13          7        1.8
         5         30         18 1.66666667
         6         10          5          2
```

The first branch of the case expression needs an aggregate because you aren't grouping by amount; and the `sum(nvl(rates,null))` can just be `sum(rates)`. If you're expecting any null rates then you need to decide how you want the amount to be handled, but `nvl(rates,null)` isn't doing anything.

You can do the same thing without a case expression if you prefer, manipulating all the values - which might be more expensive:

```
select id, 
  cash as new_cash,
  sum(rates) as new_rates,
  sum(amount * rates)/sum(rates) as new_amount
from cash_table
group by id, cash
order by id
```